# How to allow access to Webform Submission Grid results to Role

Tags: 8, webforms

### Giving admin privileges to sales dept seems bad.

The Webform Customized submissions is super!  However I am unable to create a link for my Sales manager to view the same data without giving admin privileges. (D8 Webform Version: 8.x-5.4)

> //mycompanysite.com/admin/structure/webform/manage/sales_appts/results/submissions
>   [image: Webform Custom]

Since we cannot select Grid as the format in Views for webform submissions data, the unformatted layout is inferior to the customized version of the Webform/manage layout.

Comment: really ? should this just be view submissions in webfor settings ?

Comment: View submissions displays the fields stacked rather than in a grid with headings as shown in the manage-customized version